# the difference between clank and clatter

Tags: word-difference

This can be a very basic, even boring question for native English speakers. But for me who is a non-native English speaker, the words, **clank** and **clatter** are a little hard to understand each precisely. So I would like to ask about the difference between **clank** and **clatter**.

From Google's English dictionary, **clank** is defined as follows.

> a loud, sharp sound or series of sounds, typically made by pieces of metal meeting or being struck together.

**clatter** is defined as follows.

> a continuous rattling sound as of hard objects falling or striking each other.

From the example sentences in dictionaries I think **clank** describes a more high-pitched sound whereas **clatter** denotes a lower, but more continuous and louder sound. Am I right?

Further explanations will be greatly helpful and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: To me, "clank" is a single sound, or maybe a sound that is exactly and regularly repeated (think hitting two pieces of metal together either once or rhythmically repeated). "Clatter" is a series of sounds that are irregular (think of shaking a box of metal objects around). There is no difference in pitch or volume.

Comment: ***Clanking*** sounds almost always involve ***metal on metal***, whereas ***clonking*** and ***clunking*** usually imply ***lower-pitched*** sounds that don't necessarily involve metal. And ***clinking*** is a ***higher-pitched*** sound, more likely involving ***glass*** (on metal or another piece of glass). A ***clatter*** usually just means any loud noise produced by multiple hard objects bumping together (often more or less ***rhythmically / repeatedly***, as might be produced by multiple noisy linkages in an engine, or a train running over points, for example).

Answer (score 4):

There is a term - [onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) - that means a word that phonetically imitates the sound it describes.  Both "clank" and "clatter" are somewhat onomatopoeic and the two sounds differ in *rhythm and repetition*, not in pitch or volume.

**Clank** is a single-syllable word that begins and ends with a harsh */k/* sound. It describes a single, sharp metallic sound.  That sound might be repeated, but each individual **clank** is an isolated sound, just like the single-syllable word "clank" itself. Someone describing a sound might actually use the word "clank," spoken emphatically, as the sound itself:

> I was driving home and all of a sudden I heard the engine go **'clank!'** and now my car won't start again.

That's typical for an onomatopoeia: the use of the word itself to imitate the sound.

**Clatter** is a two-syllable word with a strong syllable and a weak one, with the weak syllable ending in the mild consonant */r/*.  It describes a series of sounds that vary in volume, like continuously shaking a box full of silverware back and forth.  And again, you might hear an onomatopoeic use of the word in place of the sound itself:

> Every time I'm pressing the gas pedal, I hear the car go **'clatter-clatter-clatter'** so I'm taking it to the mechanic.

Comment: +1 for the bit about repetition. I think _clank_ is generally an isolated sound, while _clatter_ describes a more chaotic commotion.

Answer (score 2):

A **clanking** is a sound made by a relatively heavy piece of metal striking another piece of dense and heavy metal, for example, a metal pipe wrench striking a cast iron pipe,  or a metal halyard striking against a flagpole on a windy day.  Clanks tend to be at relatively even intervals.

A **clatter** is a less dull sound, and a more chaotic sound, and can be made by lightweight objects.  If you drop a pie tin or an aluminum cookie tray down a flight a stairs, or a folding chair whether it's made of metal or wood, they will make a (frightful) **clatter**.